# HTML Horizontal overflow visible, Vertical overflow scroll

Tags: html

I need to have a scrollbar for vertical content that overflows from the content div, but I need the overflowing content from the X stay visible. Is it possible? Sorry for the lack of details.

My current code is:

overflow-y: scroll;

overflow-x: visible;

This code does what it should for the Y axis, but it produces a scrollbar for the X axis as-well. I need it to show that content and not clip it.

Thanks for the help, I am pretty sure the answer is going to make me sound like a total coding dummy. I googled for this for about 5 hours and its now 4:30 AM. I need this project done ASAP. Once again, thanks!

Comment: We need a jsfiddle demo. but would it better if you say nothing about the overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant, but you can set it to scroll only in overflow like this:

```
#something {
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

But you might as well want to try it like this:

```
#something {
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

This will produce scrollbars only where you need them.

Of course you should probably try just to remove everything about the overflow-x property, that might work as well

Answer (score 0):

So sorry guys, I fixed it. Maybe someone else can learn from this so I am going to post what I did. I Just created another DIV, set it to the size of the image and set top to the position of the text I need it by. Then, I created another DIV for the rest of the content and shifted it over. Now, there is the main scrolling div with 2 divs inside of it. Each hold the content.